# Oracle SQl converting weeks in days

Tags: sql, oracle

i need to convert the weeks in days without making duplicates.

I will use this table example.

| ID | Item | Weekdate | TotalQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 0 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 421 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 4525 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 3465 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 75 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 943 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 0 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 0 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 543 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 375 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 0 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 0 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 8945 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 0 |

What i really looking for is this example.

| ID | Item | Weekdate | TotalQty | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 0 | 24-SEP-23 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 421 | 25-SEP-23 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 4525 | 26-SEP-23 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 3465 | 27-SEP-23 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 75 | 28-SEP-23 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 943 | 29-SEP-23 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 24-SEP-23 | 0 | 30-SEP-23 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 0 | 01-OCT-23 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 543 | 02-OCT-23 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 375 | 03-OCT-23 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 0 | 04-OCT-23 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 0 | 05-OCT-23 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 8945 | 06-OCT-23 |
| 2 | 10AP | 01-OCT-23 | 0 | 07-OCT-23 |

I tried to do it with this example but it's making 6 additional columns for every column..

```
select a.*, a.weekdate + column_value -1 as Days from table a cross join table (cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by level <= 7 as sys.odcinumberlist)))
```

I'm tring to avoid using pl SQL code in SQL but I had to try everything I knew.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain clearly how you get from your starting table to your result. You seem to be assuming some order in the table - why is the row for 421 the 25th; or in other words how do you know that the 421 is the second value for that week? The table doesn't seem to have anything you can order by, and there is no intrinsic ordering in a SQL table?

Comment: @AlexPoole Sorry for the short explanation.. my table has passed tru a lot of joins and to simplify it i just put the first day of the week Sunday..  Since i have my answer I will add more details later. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL (not just Oracle's dialect) result sets are unordered unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause. Your data does not appear to have any way of determining which order the data should appear as the `weekdate` values are all identical.

Assuming that the data is pre-ordered by some mechanism that you have not shared with us then you can use:

```sql
-- Sample pre-ordered data
WITH pre_ordered_data ( ID, Item, Weekdate, TotalQty ) AS (
SELECT 1, '1001REP', DATE '2023-09-24',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '1001REP', DATE '2023-09-24',  421 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '1001REP', DATE '2023-09-24', 4525 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '1001REP', DATE '2023-09-24', 3465 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '1001REP', DATE '2023-09-24',   75 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '1001REP', DATE '2023-09-24',  943 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '1001REP', DATE '2023-09-24',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '10AP',    DATE '2023-10-01',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '10AP',    DATE '2023-10-01',  543 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '10AP',    DATE '2023-10-01',  375 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '10AP',    DATE '2023-10-01',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '10AP',    DATE '2023-10-01',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '10AP',    DATE '2023-10-01', 8945 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '10AP',    DATE '2023-10-01',    0 FROM DUAL
)

-- Actual query on the pre-ordered data
SELECT p.*,
       weekdate
       + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id, weekdate
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
         )
       - 1 AS days
FROM   pre_ordered_data p
```

Which outputs:

| ID | ITEM | WEEKDATE | TOTALQTY | DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001REP | 2023-09-24 00:00:00 | 0 | 2023-09-24 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 2023-09-24 00:00:00 | 421 | 2023-09-25 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 2023-09-24 00:00:00 | 4525 | 2023-09-26 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 2023-09-24 00:00:00 | 3465 | 2023-09-27 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 2023-09-24 00:00:00 | 75 | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 2023-09-24 00:00:00 | 943 | 2023-09-29 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 1001REP | 2023-09-24 00:00:00 | 0 | 2023-09-30 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 10AP | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 10AP | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 543 | 2023-10-02 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 10AP | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 375 | 2023-10-03 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 10AP | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 2023-10-04 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 10AP | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 2023-10-05 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 10AP | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 8945 | 2023-10-06 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 10AP | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 2023-10-07 00:00:00 |

If you do have a mechanism for ordering the rows by day (typically another column) then use that:

```sql
SELECT u.*,
       weekdate
       + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id, weekdate
           ORDER BY your_extra_column_that_orders_the_days
         )
       - 1 AS days
FROM   unordered_data u
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qr_N0ip0)

Comment: Thank you very much, i was struggling for hours and i couldn't find how to do it.